vision camera alignment issue
sample captured image
I am using react native vision camera in my react native cli app, I am able to successfully scan the code but there is a problem with the alignment.
Basically, when clicked on a scan button, a modal is opened up with the qr code in the center. The problem is the qr code sometimes goes to the top left corner.
I tried margin: 'auto', flex, and positioning property. But after 5 successful run the camera again goes to the top left corner
const device = useCameraDevice('back');
  if (device == null) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text className="text-black">Device not fount</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


{showCamera && (
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => setShowCamera(false)}
          style={[
            {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)'},
          ]}
          className=" absolute top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0">
          <View style={styles.Container}>
            <Camera
              style={styles.camera}
              device={device}
              isActive={true}
              codeScanner={codeScanner}
            />
            {/* Buttons */}
            <View className="my-5">
              // close and refresh button
            </View>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
      )}


I observe the docs and saw the camera style is always style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} so rather than giving width and heigh to the camera component I wrap it inside a View and give the wdith and height to the VIew and absoluteFill to the camera. And it worked well
<View className="h-[300px] w-[300px] overflow-hidden rounded-[24px]">
  <Camera
   style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
   device={device}
   isActive={true}
   codeScanner={codeScanner}
 />
</View>

